# chat using UCWA

Tags: c#, asp.net, lync, ucwa

I am trying to implement a 2-way chat using UCWA(Lync web app) , I am able to send the data to a client , but how do i receive it back from that client ? to implement a proper 2-way chat ?

I have attached the code to send some ping to a specific user , how do i receive data back from the user to implement the chat ?

```
       private void StarConversation(string startConversationLink, string hostName, string accessToken, string tokenType)
    {
        var myObject = new JObject();
        myObject.Add("operationId", Guid.NewGuid().ToString().Replace("-", ""));
        myObject.Add("to", "sip:xyz@abcd.com");
        myObject.Add("subject", "TestConv");
        List<string> outgoing = new List<string>();
        List<string> incoming = new List<string>();
        List<string> timeout = new List<string>();
        JObject href = new JObject();
        string sending = "Hey there ! how are you doing ?";
        href.Add("href", "data:text/plain;base64," + Convert.ToBase64String(System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(sending)));
        JObject message = new JObject();
        message.Add("message", href);
        myObject.Add("_links", message);
       HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Authorization", tokenType + " " + accessToken);
        client.PostAsync(new Uri(hostName + startConversationLink), new StringContent(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(myObject), Encoding.UTF8, "application/json")).Result;
        if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
        {

            Uri temp = new Uri(hostName + m_eventsLink);
            HttpResponseMessage response2 = Get(client, temp.ToString());
            string nextLink = string.Empty;
            string timeo ;
            string ss = string.Empty;
             int i =0;
            if (response2.IsSuccessStatusCode)
            {
                string retData2 = response2.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
                var o = JObject.Parse(retData2);
                nextLink = o["_links"]["next"]["href"].Value<string>();

                response = client.PostAsync(new Uri(hostName + startConversationLink), new StringContent(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(myObject), Encoding.UTF8, "application/json")).Result;
                temp = new Uri(hostName + m_eventsLink);
                response2 = Get(client, temp.ToString());
                retData2 = response2.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
                o = JObject.Parse(retData2);

            }



             }
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

What you are doing at this point is starting a Conversation with the user and providing an initial message to go with the messagingInvitation.  What I do not know from this code slice is:

- Are you listening to Events? (*This is really important as this is how you will know that the 2nd party accepted/declined the messagingInvitation among other things like who is typing and messages*).  I would suggest looking into [GettingStarted-Events](http://ucwa.lync.com/documentation/GettingStarted-Events) and setting up a mechanism to request events.
- Are you making frequent (~3-5min) POST request on reportMyActivity to ensure the application is not recycled.  Check out [Resources-reportMyActivity](http://ucwa.lync.com/documentation/Resources-reportMyActivity) if not.

If the code is listening to events and reporting activity.  The next step will be listening for the [messagingInvitation](http://ucwa.lync.com/documentation/Resources-messagingInvitation) and check [conversation](http://ucwa.lync.com/documentation/Resources-conversation)/[messaging](http://ucwa.lync.com/documentation/Resources-messaging) events.  Conversation will transition from Connecting (*state*) (messageInvitation is being processed) to Connected (messagingInvitation was accepted) or Disconnected (messagingInvitation was declined, conversation ended, other errors).  Assuming the other user accepts the next event to check is messaging state for Connected (this means the messaging modality is active in the conversation and useful methods like [sendMessage](http://ucwa.lync.com/documentation/Resources-sendMessage), [addParticipant](http://ucwa.lync.com/documentation/Resources-addParticipant), and [setIsTyping](http://ucwa.lync.com/documentation/Resources-setIsTyping) will be available) or Disconnected (this means messaging modality is not active and [addMessaging](http://ucwa.lync.com/documentation/Resources-addMessaging) can be used to enable this modality.

If you can reach this point [message](http://ucwa.lync.com/documentation/Resources-message) events will appear when any participant sends a message to the conversation.  The direction property can be used to determine when the current UCWA user has sent a message (outgoing) and for all other users there should be a participant property that can identify the user.